# mkvmerge in a bash script does not execute

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have made a script which does mux a videofile, multiple audiofiles and multiple subtitles into one .mkv.

the script tries to run:
`"/usr/bin/mkvmerge" -o "test.mkv" "--default-track" "0:yes" "--forced-track" "0:no" "--display-dimensions" "0:853x462" "-d" "0" "-A" "-S" "-T" "(" "mux.mkv" ")" "--language" "0:eng" "--default-track" "0:yes" "--forced-track" "0:no" "--no-global-tags" "--no-chapters" "-a" "0" "-D" "-S" "-T" "(" "test_eng_1.opus" ")" "--default-track" "0:no" "--forced-track" "0:no" "--no-global-tags" "--no-chapters" "-a" "0" "-D" "-S" "-T" "(" "test_und_2.opus" ")" "--language" "0:eng" "--default-track" "0:no" "--forced-track" "0:no" "--no-global-tags" "--no-chapters" "-s" "0" "-D" "-A" "-T" "(" "test_eng_3.idx" ")" "--language" "0:fra" "--default-track" "0:no" "--forced-track" "0:no" "--no-global-tags" "--no-chapters" "-s" "0" "-D" "-A" "-T" "(" "test_fra_5.idx" ")" "--language" "0:spa" "--default-track" "0:no" "--forced-track" "0:no" "--no-global-tags" "--no-chapters" "-s" "0" "-D" "-A" "-T" "(" "test_spa_4.idx" ")" "--title" "test"`

If I run the script it shows: line 214: (the stuff above): No such file or directory

If I copy and paste the output and run it in bash all runs OK:

```
mkvmerge v7.7.0 ('Six Voices') 64bit built on Mar  3 2015 16:43:14 ... 
Muxing took 3 seconds.
```

Here is the part of the script which tries to run mkvmerge:

```
213 mux="\"/usr/bin/mkvmerge\" -o \"$gname.mkv\" $muxvideo$muxaudio$muxsub$tacks$title"
214 "$mux"
```

Why does it run in the terminal but not in the script?

Comment: You appear to be mixing/comparing apples and some other kind of fruit. You're not doing the same thing in the terminal and in the script, are you? Did you type `mux="\"/usr/bin/mkvmerge\" -o …"` and then `"$mux"`? Why are you assigning the entire command to a variable like that (in the script)? Just do the same thing in the script that works in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Your script defines a variable `mux` with its value being the big long `mkvmerge` command you pasted, literally with all those double quotes and everything: notice how the double quotes are backslash-escaped so that they get included literally in the string.

Then it does:

```
"$mux"
```

Which tries to run a command named after the contents of that variable, spaces and quotes and all. Since there is no command called `"/usr/bin/mkvmerge" -o "test.mkv" "--default-track"` etc..., you get the error.

Are you sure that line shouldn't be this?

```
eval "$mux"
```

...which would parse the contents of `$mux` as a shell command line, thus interpreting all those spaces and double quotes as shell syntax instead of treating it literally?

Or much more simply... just execute `mkvmerge` with all the right arguments without first building a quoted command and stuffing it into a variable and then executing the variable as a command.

Comment: Thanks, that was it... had no clue :) My first big script :)))